# What word means both "advantages and disadvantages"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, is-it-a-word

So I am writing an essay and I can't find the word I want to use. The sentence says:

> When I travelled to England there were pros and cons.

The sentence doesn't sound right and if I change it to:

> Travelling to England had it's pros and cons.

then it's a bit wordy and it doesn't clearly state that I was the one who travelled.

What word can I use instead of "pros and cons"? 
I want the meaning to be something like this:

> When I travelled to England there was some good stuff and some bad stuff.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Consider **mixed experience**:

> Traveling to England was a **mixed experience**

I've heard this phrase used to refer to an experience that had its pluses and minuses. Example:

> *A Mixed Experience*. Fern does many things **very well**. ... In other areas, however, Fern **fell short** of our expectations.

([A review on TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g182145-d182960-r219431760-Fern_Resort-Orillia_Ontario.html))

Alternatively, how about **flip side**:

> Traveling to England was great overall, but there was **a flip side**.

Definition:

> the negative aspects of an idea, plan, or situation

([Macmillan English Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/flip-side))

Answer (score 2):

"Pros and cons" is primarily used for evaluating the utility of a thing or of a manner of doing something. I wouldn't use it to describe something like a life experience.

I don't have a single word for you, but I do have suggestions for re-wording:

> I have both positive and negative memories of my trip to England.
>
> I had both positive and negative experiences while in England.
>
> My travels in England had both high and low points.

Answer (score 2):

How about "My journey to England had its **ups and downs**." That's a gentle way of saying there were good and bad moments in the journey.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the phrase **pluses and minuses** used in this manner before.

Also **advantages and disadvantages** is at least occasionally used.

Answer (score 1):

There are other well-used phrases, such as *good and bad points*, *good side and bad side*, or simply *good and bad*. You can be a bit softer, and say *has its good side but also its not-so-good ...*

However is it necessary to actually say it? Every country has its good and bad (not-so-good) side, so at one level it is self evident.  Can't you simply just dive right in and describe the good things (history, culture, beautiful buildings), and then balance that with things you didn't like as much (the traffic, the many accents, the warm beer)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the single word you are seeking exists, but a couple of near matches that you might consider are ***equivocal*** and ***indeterminate***.

***When I travelled to England the benefits were equivocal/indeterminate***

Comment: *We tested the equivocalness of cricket bats versus baseball bats while fighting zombies.* Is that the same as, *we tested the pros and cons of...* ?

Comment: @Mazura Well, I certainly wouldn't use a word like "equivocalness". "Pros and cons" does the job much better.

Answer (score 0):

“Experiences” is pretty neutral.

If the good ones outnumbered the bad ones you’d really only have to mention “the few bad ones” [& could omit the bracketed ‘but’ clause]:

“My experiences [as a traveler] in England included a few bad ones. [but overall I had a great time.]”

If the bad ones outnumbered the good ones you’d really only have to mention “the few good ones” [again, without needing the bracketed ‘but’ clause]:

“My experiences [as a traveler] in England included a few good ones. [but overall I was disappointed.]”

If it was 50/50 you’d probably need to mention both:

“My experiences [as a traveler] in England included both good and bad ones.”
[which is totally normal, btw]